# How do I format multiple ids in the bugtraq:message property of TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I would like to enter a comma delimited list of issue numbers in the text box that tortoiseSVN provides when you set the bugtraq:message property. And I would like to format each number in the appended log message. Example:

If I put into the text box "123,124,125"

I would like the appended message to read:
Issue(s): #123, #124, #125

The reason I would like this format is the bugtraq:logregex I am using is looking for a '#' and a number.

```
#(\d+)(?:, #(\d+))?
```

Is there a way to do this using the bugtraq:message property, or is my only option to set the id type to arbitrary text and manually put the '#' in?